# Two definitions of order embedding, and the reason why one is correct and the other is not

Tags: definition, order-theory

I have two definitions of **order embedding** and I present the reasoning for their difference below. Please check if my understanding is correct! Thank you so much!

---

Definition 1:

> Let $(A, \prec_1)$, $(B, \prec_2)$ be ordered sets and $f:A\to B$ be a mapping.
>
> Then $f$ is an **order embedding** of $A$ into $B$ if and only if $$\forall x, y \in A: x \preceq_1 y \iff f(x) \preceq_2 f(y)$$

I replace $\preceq$ with $\prec$ in the condition and I get the Definition 2.

Definition 2:

> Let $(A, \prec_1)$, $(B, \prec_2)$ be ordered sets and $f:A\to B$ be a mapping.
>
> Then $f$ is an **order embedding** of $A$ into $B$ if and only if $$\forall x, y \in A: x \prec_1 y \iff f(x) \prec_2 f(y)$$

---

I think that the Definition 1 is correct, while the Definition 2 is not. This is because $f$ in Definition 1 is injective, while $f$ in Definition 1 is not necessarily injective.

First, I give an counter example for Definition 2:

> Let $A=\{a,b,c\},B=\{x,y\}$ and $f(a)=f(b)=x,f(c)=y$. The partial order $\prec_1$ in $A$ is that $a \prec_1 c,b \prec_1 c$. The total order $\prec_2$ in $B$ is that $x \prec_2 y$.
>
> We can verify $$a \prec_1 c \iff f(a)=x \prec_2 f(c)=y$$ and 
>   $$b \prec_1 c \iff f(b)=x \prec_2 f(c)=y$$
>
> Hence $f$ satisfies the requirement of Definition 2, but $f$ is not injective.

On the other hand, the added equality $=$ in the condition of Definition 1 provides us information about $x,y$ even when $f(x)=f(y)$, i.e. $f(x)=f(y) \implies f(x)\preceq_2 f(y) \implies x\preceq_1 y$. Similarly, $f(x)=f(y) \implies f(y)\preceq_2 f(x) \implies y\preceq_1 x$. Thus $f(x)=f(y) \implies x\preceq_1 y$ and $y\preceq_1 x\implies x=y$.

It's clear that the strict inequality in the condition in Definition 2 tells us nothing about $x,y$ in case $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: When you say "ordered" do you mean... partially? totally? pre?

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila! I mean *order* in general. My textbook and Wikipedia give the definition of order embedding with the term *order*. They don't mention *partial* and *total*, just the term *order*.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I quite don't understand what you meant. When I mention *order*, I mean order relation.

Comment: What do you mean by "the term order relation". Is it a **total** order relation? is it just a **partial** order relation? is it a **pre**-order relation? is it a **well** order relation? *What* kind of order?

Comment: For definition $1$ to work, you need the anti-symmetry of the order of your domain.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant partial order.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Anti-symmetry is an inherent property of partial order (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Partially_ordered_set#/Formal_definition).

Comment: @Akira, In your statement you hadn't mentioned that it's a p.o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a duality to all these definitions. Sometime reflexivity makes things simpler, sometimes it makes them more complicated.

For example, $A$ is an antichain if for every $a,b\in A$, if $a\leq b$ then $a=b$. But in the strict order, $A$ is an antichain if for every $a,b\in A$, $a\nless b$.

Similarly, $A$ is a chain if for every $a,b\in A$ either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$. But in the strict order, $A$ is a chain if for every $a,b\in A$ either $a<b$ or $b<a$ or $a=b$.

---

In the definition of an order embedding when talking about a reflexive case, injectivity is a theorem. But then when you move to strict orders, you need to require it explicitly. As you noted.

Of course, some conditions let you omit injectivity (e.g. a linear order, or more generally extensionality). But in general, you need to require it explicitly.

Comment: You meant that injectivity is a theorem that can be proved from my Definition 1, i.e. injectivity is implied by Definition 1. On the other hand, for Definition 2 to work, it must added the condition that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Exactly. ${} {}$

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess that my understanding in my post is correct.